# Passing data from listbox navigation Windows Phone

Tags: json, listbox, windows-phone-7.1, listboxitem

I'm getting data to create a Listbox like a blog with JSON from a webblog, I want to pass this data when you select one item, to another simple xaml page with the information of this news(Title, content and Image). How can I get all the values for a new page with the information of the selected Item of the list?

I have this code for the listBox:

```
            <ListBox x:Name="NewsList" Margin="0,200,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="100">
                                <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                                <Image x:Name="Imagen" Height="100" Width="100"  Margin="12,0,9,0">
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding LineThree}" />
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                                <StackPanel Width="311">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="Titulo" Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="18.667" FontFamily="Tahoma" Margin="12,0,12,6"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="Contenido" Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" FontSize="16"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

I get the values from the news here :
Items is the list where I add the values of the news(Title, content, and Image)

```
 public void LoadData()
    {
        WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://automaticband.es/blog/", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
        Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://automaticband.es/blog/?json=get_recent_post");
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        downloader.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(downloader_OpenReadCompleted);
        downloader.OpenReadAsync(serviceUri);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    void downloader_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            try
            {
                Stream responseStream = e.Result;
                DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Posts));
                Posts response = (Posts)ser.ReadObject(responseStream);
                if (response.posts != null && response.posts.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Post post in response.posts)
                    {

                        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = post.title, LineTwo = post.excerpt,
                            LineThree = post.thumbnail});
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                return;
            }
            this.IsDataLoaded = true;
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here :

http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-MVVM-Master---Details-Navigation-in-5-minutes

Easy way to pass data between pages with ItemViewModel.